# C returning character string count and character string issues (rusty in C....)

Tags: c, arrays, character, scanf, c-strings

OK, so here I am trying to get back into C for a course that starts this upcoming semester. I have not used C in about ten years, and I am having some issues here.....

I am trying a simple program that is supposed to use a method getword() that accepts a pointer to a character string array as an argument.

The method is to be delimited by a tab character '\t', the EOF signal, or a newline character '\n'. The method is also to return the length of the current word that it found in the character string array....

I was finally able to (sort of) get it to work; but I have two unique issues that I could use some guidance on: 
ONE: How can I get it to read a character string with a space in it? 
TWO: How can I properly flush the input so it stops reading the last word from getword repeatedly?

Here is all the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "getword.h"

int main(){

    char s[255];
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(scanf("%s", s)){
        printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", getword(s), s);

        fflush(stdout);

    }
    return 0;
}

int getword(char *w){
    int c;
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\0' && c != EOF ){
        w[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    }
    return (int)strlen(w);
}
```

When I run this as is, using the input "no-brainer\tone\t\n" the output displays what I hope for, but DOES NOT STOP THE APPLICATION:

```
Enter text: no-brainer  one 
n=10, s=[no-brainer]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
n=3, s=[one]
```

I dont know how to flush the input once it reads both words delimited by a tab as above so it stops reading just the last one it read and outputting those values.....essentially I want it to output just the first two lines under "Enter text: no-brainer     one"

My second issue that I can't find a work around for is when there is a space in the char string to be read. For this application, a word like "house cat" with a space is ONE WORD and should be read as n=9. When I try to use

```
scanf("%[^\n]", s)
```

as the input, it will properly read "house cat" and say n=10 (no doubt because of \0 or \n but I can deal with that later) but it will no longer properly read "no-brainer\tone\t\n" as it did before, instead it reads the whole line for "no-brainer\tone\t\n" and outputs n=16.

So is there another way to do this while reading a space character and still including that as a character in the "word" for the getword() function?

EDIT: 
Thanks for the suggestions! Still having some problems though, for example, when using while(getword(s) > 0) it never seems to read the first part of any line, only the parts after the first whitespace.......no Idea why. Using teh other suggestion does something similar....... for further clarification, I am basically trying to do a basic, simple lexical analyzer (super super basic) and the output I am TRYING to achieve, with the input of "no-brainer\tone\t" (no-brainer     one     <---each with a tab after the word) should look like:

```
n=10 s=[no-brainer]
n=3 s=[one]
n=0 s=[] <<<<<<<When \n is read
n=-1 s=[] <<<<<<<for when EOF or \0 is reached.
```

input of "house cat" with a SPACE should output:

```
n=9 s=[house cat]
```

right now, I can get ONE OR THE OTHER TO GIVE PROPER OUTPUT(but application wont terminate, ill get to that later), but NOT BOTH, and I really believe both SHOULD be able to be done in the same function....also keep in mind for the purposes of what I am trying to do here, I don't care that the string will get overwritten since its a pointer.....just want it to output the intended output

I tried something like this just now, but still not working as intended :(

```
    int c;
int counter;
counter = 0;
w[0] = '\0';
while((c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    if(c == EOF && strlen(w) == 0){
        return c;
    } else if(c == '\n' && strlen(w) == 0){
        return 0;
    }else if(c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    w[counter] = c;
    counter++;

}
w[counter] = '\0';
return (int)strlen(w);
```

Comment: You don't seem to null terminate the string, so strlen will go bananas.

Comment: You do a `scanf`, which consumes input, and in `getword` you do `getchar`, which also consumes input. Make up your mind, but don't do both.

Comment: Instead of `while(scanf` do `while(getword` and don't forget to first set `w[0]='\0';` and to terminate `w` before calling `strlen`

Comment: You read a string into `s`, pass it to `getword` and completely ignore that string but replace it by another one. Doesn't make much sense IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

The first issue, your program DOES NOT STOP THE APPLICATION. because in the while loop 
    while(scanf("%s", s)){
scanf will return number of characters written if success, otherwise a negative number is returned. int means this while loop is non-stop.

The second issue, you should use fgets as a replacement.

ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int getword(char *w);
int main(){

    char s[255];
    int len = 0;

    len = getword(s);
    printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", len, s);

    return 0;
}

int getword(char *w)
{
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    w[0] = '\0';
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\0' && c != EOF )
    {
        w[0] = c;
        fgets(w+1, 255, stdin);
        counter = strlen(w);
    }
    w[--counter] = '\0';
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: hmmm, while those made sense upon reading this morning, upon execution, this is not performing as intended :(. Using that it wont read "no-brainer"      but it will read n=3 and output s= one, basically the latter half of the string. still playing with this to see what I can do to fix........

Comment: `scanf` does not return a count of characters written because `scanf` is used for reading, not writing. `scanf` returns the number of items successfully read (which can be 0 if the first item failed) or `EOF` if the end of input was reached before any item could be read. For `scanf("%s", s)` there is only a single item (`%s`), so the possible return values are `1`, `0`, and `EOF`.